# multiple ftp sites on a single iis server with one ip

Tags: web, iis-6, ftp

can i have multiple iis ftp sites using something similar to web site's unasigned host headers?

i have a dedicated server in a hosting facility and want to make a web site for each of my clients. to add/ remove files and content i want ftp access to each of the sites root folders.

lets say i have 10 sites set up using unasigned host headers... how can i set up 10 analogous ftp sites on the same server? AND NOT USE A DEFINED IP ADDRESS FOR EACH FTP SITE

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more suited for serverfault.

Also, I wouldn't use the built-in Windows FTP server. Check out Filezilla Server. It's free and can handle a bunch of users, sites, etc. on one IP.

Also, drop dead easy to configure.